# jcarousel or any other image slider that looks like that

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jcarousel, jcarousellite

I've been looking for a image slider just like jcarousel with infinite loop, (circular)
anyways, I wanted something that when I press the next button only moves one image, but I was ok with jcarousel, the thing is every site I see with the demos work fine in chrome FF etc.. all but IE, here's is an example

[link text](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html)

I just want something like that that works from IE6 on, and in any other browser! 
I've been looking but I dont seem to get an answer, maybe I have something disabled in my IE8
I also try everything in IeTester.
Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I attached them on my blog. They are useful only on white background.
http://soofit.blogspot.com/2010/12/problem-with-prev-next-buttons-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Ask somebody for an image substitution (graphic designer). You can  replace it with a text, ie lessthan sign(<).